# permanently hide "infos" from problems panel in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When clicking on the "funnel" icon in the filter line of the "Problems" view of vscode, it is possible to hide "infos" from the view by un-checking "Show Infos". However, at each start of the editor, the "infos" (in my case spelling errors) come back, and I have to uncheck the option anew. Is there a global setting that unsets this option by default?

Edit: output of `Help: About`

```
Version: 1.79.2
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:59:55.818Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-47-generic
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. I'm asking this because of https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/172648. also related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95484

Comment: @starball done! interesting, so it's supposed to do that already ... I hadn't seen these bug reports even after repeated googling.

Comment: it's working fine for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2 with VS Code 1.79.2 installed as a snap. I'd encourage you to post a bug report and provide as much detail as possible. Use the `Help: Report Issue...` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Once you've created your issue ticket, please [edit] your question post to add a link to it.